# What is the benefit of having $sce or Strict Contextual Escaping in angularjs and why react does not need to do it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, javascript-framework

I am puzzled by the fact that I can't really see the true benefit of having SCE in angularjs (even after read the doc) regarding security benefit and wonder why react does not need to have such SCE in it?

So question just to regroup:

1. The benefit of SCE
2. Why Angular does it but React does not?

Comment: Are you not familiar with the types of vulnerabilities it is intended to reduce (e.g., XSS, clickjacking) or do you not see how it helps to reduce them?

Comment: React has `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for the same reason. By default it automatically escapes HTML and you have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: @JackA. I think @sergiu answered the 2nd part which clarified a mis-conception I had, and I think what you said is true as well, like what can a person do to a react app when the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is not used? can a person actually execute server side script just because, let say  `text = <span>0&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;` in a react.js file?

Comment: In React if you use `{text}` then it'll be automatically escaped and nothing bad can happen. So by default you are protected. If you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}}` then it's your responsibility to sanitize `text` so nothing bad happens, that's why the name ***dangerously*** :)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv ah... thats really interesting! very useful to know, so actually `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` should not really be an encouraged way to prevent XSS as what angular does, right ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In React if you use `{text}` then it'll be automatically escaped and nothing bad can happen. So by default you are protected. If you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}}` then it's your responsibility to sanitize `text` so nothing bad happens, that's why the name **dangerously** :)

Angular has a similar approach. It handles any string as possibly having dangerous HTML inside, so it automatically escapes it.
`$sce` is in essence React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, in that it wraps your text in an object telling Angular that `{sceWrappedText}` should not be automatically escaped. And, just like in React, it's your responsibility to sanitize it.

`$sce` does come with some helper sanitizers like `parseAsHtml` that you can use to sanitize the HTML before outputing it. I think it uses the `$sanitize` service and removes stuff like `ng-click` and such.

**To clarify**: neither `$sce` nor `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` should be used thinking they will magically make unsafe (user inputed) strings safe to display as HTML. They exist because *by default* everything is escaped. You as a developer are responsible to decide what is safe to use:

- it comes from the server where it was sanitized;
- you sanitized it using some client-side code (https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer, https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html, and many many others)
- it's a piece of HTML you glued together from pieces that are by nature safe (think `'<b>' + parseInt(this.props.numberFromTextInput, 10) + '</b>'`)

What *default* means:

Controller:

```
$scope.text = '<b>foo</b>';
```

Template:

```
<div>{{text}}</div>
```

Would output "Hello, `<b>foo</b>`!"

While

`$scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>foo</b>');`

would output "Hello, ***foo***!"

Same with React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` where `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<b>foo</b>'}} />` would output "Hello, ***foo***!" while `<div>{'<b>foo</b>'}</div>` would be escaped.

Comment: May I have an elaboration on `They exist so that by default everything is escaped.` I am not really clear which `default` it means? Like, does it mean, by default means, the moment before the data sent to server? or means something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "They exist because"

Comment: Thanks a huge bunch :)

Comment: "In React if you use {text} then it'll be automatically escaped and nothing bad can happen."

This is definitely not true. React doesn't provide contextual auto-escaping so rendering a link like the following `<a href='javascript:console.log("XSS!")'>XSS</a>` can execute arbitrary javascript. Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xss-demo-cibwm.

Comment: @AnthonyE the original question, and my answer, are about sanitising HTML, not JS, IMO. Indeed, `$sce.trustAsJs` exists, but we're talking about different things.